# How can i get the id of the selected product on firestore web?

Tags: javascript, html, google-cloud-firestore

how can i get the value of the selected item from firebase firestore i used `innerHTML` to list my products on my page and each of them has a button and when i hit the button i want to get the `id` of the product which is holding the button.
this is my js `inneHTML` and firestore `getter`

```
database.collection("product").get().then(function(querySnapshot) {
  querySnapshot.forEach(function(doc) {
    const productid = doc.data().id;
    const productname = doc.data().name;
          productsList.innerHTML += "<div class='product-container' ><div class='course'><h2>"+ productname +"</h2><h6>"+ productid +"</h6><button id='editbutton' class='btn' >Edit Product</button></div></div></div>"
        });
    })
```

Comment: It doesn't look like you've done anything at all yet to handle the click of the button.  I suggest adding that code so we can get a better idea where specifically you are stuck.

Comment: i bessically dont know how to get the value and i cant find it anywere thats why i asked @DougStevenson

Comment: Without writing code to handle the click, you have no chance of getting the ID when the button is clicked.  The first problem you have here is adding the click handler.  The second problem is making sure it has access to the ID.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to attach a click listener to the button, and then look up the ID that the user clicked on in the DOM. There are lots of ways to do that, one being:

```
productsList.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  if (e.target.localName === 'button') {
    var h6 = e.target.parentElement.getElementsByTagName("h6")[0];
    alert(h6.textContent);
  }
  return false;
});
```

Working example: https://jsbin.com/pewohax/edit?html,js,output

Comment: its working well thanks for that but it is showing me this error `index.js:28 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'textContent' of undefined at HTMLDivElement.<anonymous> ` is this okay?

Comment: `index.js:28` is this line `alert(h6.textContent);`

Comment: It looks like some elements don't have an `h6` child? If that persists, can you try to reproduce it in a site like jsbin, as I did in my answer? That ensures that we're both looking at the exact same thing.

Comment: Yes i did what you exactly did

Comment: Can you try to reproduce it in a site like jsbin, as I did in my answer?

Comment: oh sorry i dont know how i miised your comment

Comment: https://jsbin.com/xuyekuk/edit?html,css,js here is my whole css html and js

Comment: I don't need to see all your code. Instead we need a minimal reproduction of the problem, similar to the running jsbin I gave in my answer. Without that I won't be able to help beyond what I've already done.

Comment: so what are you suggesting me to do

Comment: We need a minimal reproduction of the problem, similar to the running jsbin I gave in my answer. Without seeing the new problem reproduced, it's unlikely anyone can efficiently help you solve it.

Comment: so what should i do should i remove codes you dont need?

Comment: Please study [how to create a minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), as it's not just about removing code. It's about reproducing the problem in isolation.

Comment: Sorry i didnt know how to credit i thought that was how to credit a user

Answer (score 1):

In addition of **Frank van Puffelen** answer i changed `e.target.localName === 'button'` to `e.target.id == 'button'` bacuse the first one will get every element that is a button so you change it to get it with the id of the button or any other element.

this is the full code

```
  e.preventDefault();
  if (e.target.id == 'button') {
    var h6 = e.target.parentElement.getElementsByTagName("h6")[0];
    alert(h6.textContent);
  }
  return false;
});
```

credits to **Frank van Puffelen**

Comment: Taking code from another answer and making a tweak is not enough to then constitute a new answer. If you expect people to keep helping you, I'd recommend crediting their work with more than a mention in a copy/paste/modify answer.

Comment: Sorry i didnt know how to credit you i thought this was the way what do i do